# What is "Thief Looting?"

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

One of the achievements in Assassins Creed: Revelations is to loot 50 dead guards with "thief looting."

I tried hiring some thieves and killing a few guards, but the thieves just kind of stood there and looked at me.  Looting the dead guards didn't really seem to faze them or do anything different than normal either.

What must I do in order to learn how to/execute a "thief loot?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thief looting is an ability unlocked by completing the 2nd of 3 challenges for the Thieves. You unlock it by:

- Perform 40 Leap of Faiths
- Climb a total distance of 1 km
- Steal 250 with a Counter Steal ( RT and Y as a counter on the Xbox 360 version )

After unlocking the ability, hire a band of thieves to follow you around. You then need to go on a guard killing spree. When the guards are dead, the thieves following you will automatically loot the dead bodies of the guards.

Comment: They will also pickpocket anyone they do encounter.

Comment: It definitely makes the thieves a lot more useful than they were in previous games.

Answer (score 4):

You need to complete the second set of challenges for the thief guild, you will unlock the thief looting faction ability. Then you will be able to have thieves loot bodies (they will also steal from people as you walk around with them.)

According to [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/628358-assassins-creed-revelations/61020709):

> What you have to do is hire them, then go around killing enemies.
>   After the enemies are dead, stand near them and wait for the thieves to loot
>   the corpses. This can take some coaxing on your part, just walk back
>   and forth until all of the bodies get looted. Every now and then, though
>   either a thief will die or just get lost.